# python dataframe to dictionary problem iterate unique ID and pass as list with multiple entries

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a sample like dataframe like this:

| Start | end | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | C | 2 |
| B | D | 3 |
| C | A | 2 |

How could I change it into a dict like this:

```
{
'A': [('B',1),('C',2)]
,'B': [('D',3)]
,'C': [('A',2)]
,'D':[]
}
```

thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
for i in df['Start'].unique():
    d[i] = [(df['end'][j], df['value'][j]) for j in df[df['Start']==i].index]
```